# How to add vertical line behind mouse cursor

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I use angular-chart.js (1.0.2) and chart.js (2.5.0) - due to current application angular version I can't use another version of angular-chart.js.

Question is: is there any way to create vertical line that will go behind mouse cursor? It will be conveniently on chart with lots of points.

Something like this: [example - click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjRxX.png)

Comment: see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hev1nonk/). *not sure how to implement in angular*

Comment: Thank you for example, will look into it.